# How to separate $_POST values in two two parts and insert it in database

Tags: php

i have a dynamic form like this ...

```
for($i=1;$i<=$iday;$i++)//iday define how many time this field will generate
{
    echo" <label style='color:red' for='description' > Day-$i </label ><BR>";

    echo" <label for='description' > Itinerary </label >";
    echo"    <input type = 'text' class='form-control' name = 'i$i' placeholder = 'Itinerary'required > </div > <div class='form-group' >";

    echo"   <label for='price' > Discription </label >";
    echo"    <textarea rows = '10' class='form-control' name = 'd$i' placeholder = 'Discription' ></textarea > </div > <div class='form-group' >";
}
?>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="step2" id="button" Value="Submit"> </form>
```

how could i insert the data of these field in database 
the query is like this

```
// for all data eg i2,d2 i3,d3, but in different-different rows
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO sight VALUES('','i1','d1')";
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arrays! Very small example:

```
for($i=1; $i<=$iday; $i++){
    echo "Day-$i<br />";
    echo '<input type="text" name="i['.$i.']" />';
    echo '<textarea name="d['.$i.'].'"></textarea>';
}
```

Now you can loop through them when you post:

```
foreach($_POST['i'] as $key=>$val ){
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO sight VALUES('','". $_POST['i'][$key] ."','". $_POST['d'][$key] ."')";
}
```

I've also changed the quotes. You should wrap attribute values in double quotes. There arent really any rules about this, bit in practice that'll work easier. Also, I *really* suggest better names for inputs than `i` and `d` *(I made an error in my snippet because I got confused by it haha)*.

---

*In your specific example, you could also just loop through the days again (just like you did for the inputs), but now using the `$i` in your sql string. I'm not showing how, as thta is not the way to go.*

Comment: thank's a lot its working

Answer (score -1):

Use value as array or first check entered data by `print_r($_POST);` and after this check code.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I can explain: This isnt a answer, this is a comment for under the question. While this might help to OP, it is not a solution in its whole :)